# generating pdf attachment blank when I set a password on it

Tags: php

I am setting up password for the pdf attachment that I'm going to send on email.
The PDF that I send as attachment are blank.

```
public function pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password){
    require_once('pdf_fpdi/fpdf.php');
    require_once('pdf_fpdi/fpdi.php');
    require_once('pdf_fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php');
    $pdf = new FPDI_Protection();
    $pdf->FPDF("P", "in", array('8.50','8.06'));
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

    for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
        $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
        $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplidx);//

        $pdf->addPage($pdforientation);

        $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
    }
    $pdf->SetProtection(array(),$password);

    $pdf_new_file = "payslip_email_protected.pdf";
    $pdf->Output($pdf_new_file,'F');
}
```

No error in generating it but the pdf just blank.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to set the type of permission which you want to protect with the password.

Try this:

```
public function pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password){
   require_once('pdf_fpdi/fpdf.php');
   require_once('pdf_fpdi/fpdi.php');
   require_once('pdf_fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php');

   $pdf = new FPDI_Protection();
   $pdf->SetProtection(array('print'),$password);

   $pdf->FPDF("P", "in", array('8.50','8.06'));
   $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

   for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
       $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
       $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplidx);//

       $pdf->addPage($pdforientation);

       $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
  }

  $pdf_new_file = "payslip_email_protected.pdf";
  $pdf->Output($pdf_new_file,'F');
```

}

Read more here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script37.php

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working I tried it before and I tried it again but nothing happen.

Comment: Is this FPDI working on php 7.2? cause I think it's not.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?